# Vue3: how to use provide and inject to transmit async data correctly?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuejs3

I am using vue3 with axios. And I want to get data on `FatherComponent` by axios request:

```html
<!-- Father.vue -->
<script setup>
import { onMounted, ref, provide } from "vue";
import ChildComponent from "@/components/Child.vue";
import { getForm } from "@/api/form"; 

const formData= ref({});
provide("formData", formData);

async function getData() {
    // look like: { key1: { name: 'foo' }, key2: { name: 'bar' } }
    let res = await getForm();
    formData.value = res;
}

onMounted(() => {
    getData();
});
</script>

<template>
    <div>
        <ChildComponent />
    </div>
</template>
```

And use the `formData` in `ChildComponent`:

```html
<!-- Child.vue -->
<script setup>
import { inject } from "vue";

const formData = inject("formData");
</script>

<template>
    <div>
        <div>{{ formData }}</div>
        <div>{{ formData.key1 }}</div>
    </div>
</template>
```

It works well, just the first div shows a `{}` and the second div is blank before `getForm()` has response. But if I try to get `key1`'s name, it will report a error:

```html
<!-- Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name') -->
<div>{{ formData.key1.name }}</div>
```

I was try to declear `key1` in `ref()`:

```html
// Father.vue
const formData = ref({ key1: {}, key2: {} });
```

It works but that is very annoying and is not what I need.

So I want to `provide()` the data after response, and `ChildComponent` can `inject()` the updated data directly, not the default `{}`, how can I do?